Why does the Replay XHR tool stop working?
Why are there times when you do 'Replay XHR' nothing just happens? After closing the browser and restarting it continues to work, until it crashes again in the same request.
In this interval, if you replay xhr in another request, it works. The method is POST with response in normal JSON.
Chrome 126.0.6478.127(arm64)
